# Cat D11 calibration starts then stalls

Tags: technic, control-plus

My Cat D11 lego worked perfectly a few months then it stopped having full range of movements (blade, rear ripper, stairs) but still drives ok. When I try to calibrate, it starts the process but then it stops and nothing happens (no gearbox sound or movement). Any idea what to check/do?

Comment: Does this sound like the same issue you are having? https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18325/calibration-freeze-on-d11

Comment: Yes very similar thanks!